# How to draw a 3D arrow/vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to add some arrows to a 3D surface plot to indicate important directions, similar to this one (from [povray](https://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.0/15/))

[image]

Different colors would be great and a threedimensional letter like the X in the image even more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [3D arrow plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28324-3d-arrow-plot) at the MATLAB file exchange actually does this:

[image]

Meanwhile https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14056-arrow3 turned up, which might be even better but I haven't tested it...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I used something similar to your approach thta could be a start for you: here is an example of the code:

> > q=[0 1 0 1];
> >     q=qnorm(q);
> >     x = q(1) / sqrt(1-q(4)*q(4))

x =

```
 0
```

> > y = q(2) / sqrt(1-q(4)*q(4))

y =

```
1.0000
```

> > z = q(3) / sqrt(1-q(4)*q(4))

z =

```
 0
```

> > quiver3(0, 0, 0, x, y, z)

It is a quaternion that I normalize and convert to axis components in order to draw it 3D. I also would like to be able to draw it 3D like the picture you posted.

Comment: Thanks, the quiver3 arrows are a start. Meanwhile I [found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8849391/321973) a function at the MATLAB file exchange